# Modal Immediately Closes

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Problem:** I am having an issue where when the user clicks on the modal "Privacy Notice" on the footer. Every time the user clicks on it, it immediately closes the modals. I have compared the files with what I have done before and it is the same.

I have checked if I had both **bootstrap.js** and **bootstrap.min.js** and I just only have the min js file. I have checked if I am calling the modal's twice and I am not.

The following is the path of the site: [regalmed](http://www.regalmed.com/). I unfortunately do not have access to the files but based on comparing the test site with the Privacy Notice in the footer, they look the same.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Please check browser's console, there is an error, `Uncaught ReferenceError: intialize is not defined`, this happening when website loaded, fixing this might fix your issue.

Comment: why are you calling styles on modals.css and the bootstrap modals? also, your body has the class "modal-open" even before one clicks anything

Comment: @azs06: I have checked that possibility and that is not causing the issue. The test version currently has that error.

Comment: @LordNeo: The previous developer is using both modals. I have no idea the need for both but I have no say in modify the files. The 'modal-open" appears when the user is using older versions of IE. It is a modal that pops up notifying the user about better browsers if they are using older versions of IE.

Comment: @RobertoFlores I'm using Chrome and i get the modal-open class on the body

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap is being double loaded which is causing your problem. It's loaded from the cdn in the `<head>` and then again near the bottom of the body from:

```
http://www.regalmed.com/Regal-en-us/includes/themes/MuraBootstrap3/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

Comment: @ William Robinson: Have you tried to remove it in the inspect tool. When I remove it, it is still acting the same way

Comment: Yeah... that's because you'll need to remove the script link _before_ the script is loaded. Using an inspect tool to remove the link after you've loaded the script twice doesn't unload the script.

Comment: @ William Robinson: Thank you for the clarifications